# Best way to setup sendgrid for inbound email parsing?

Tags: installation, sendgrid, incoming-mail

We are using google apps gmail for our company emails.

I want to use sendgrid for transactional mail in our web app, and I want all replies to that transactional mail to be parsed and posted to our api.

How do I set this up? Do I need to point some subdomain MX record at sendgrid and use that subdomain in the sender address for the transactional mail? Or is there some way to use the domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read through the [Parse documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html)? You need to setup a subdomain that is CNAMEd to `mx.sendgrid.net`, and then enable Parse on your SendGrid user. Any mail sent to that domain will be parsed & POSTed by SendGrid.

Comment: Yes I read that. I'm wondering what the recommended way to do that is. For example, is it typical to use a subdomain for the CName, such as mail.mydomain.com, or do people use the standard domain mydomain.com?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Changing the MX record for the whole domain means you can't receive messages to that domain other than via the webhook. So if you need to have example@domain.com as a working mailbox, then a subdomain like example@mail.domain.com is necessary. [You can also find a bunch of tutorials on the SendGrid blog](https://sendgrid.com/blog/?s=parse&submit=)

Comment: I think it should be MX record not CNAME.

Comment: No, the CNAME is the Canonical redirect, so that anyone looking up an MX record will be redirected from `sub.domain.com` to `mx.sendgrid.net`, which then serves up the relevant MX record. If it were hosting the MX record itself, it would be expected to be providing the literal Server, not just another DNS record.